# Derive pandas datetime from mix integer format

Tags: pandas, string-to-datetime

I want to derive a DateTime column from a mixed range of integer column in a panadas dataFrame. The input column is as below. As you see there is a various length of integer numbers in that column. I want to return:

```
180000 = 18:00:00
60000 = 06:00:00
0 =00:00:00

13 |180000
14 |   0
15 | 60000
16 |100000
17 |   0
18 | 60000
```

Thanks,
Pedram.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_datetime`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'].replace(0, '0'*6), format='%H%M%S', errors='coerce').dt.time
```

Result:

```
   id   value      Time
0  13  180000  18:00:00
1  14       0  00:00:00
2  15   60000  06:00:00
3  16  100000  10:00:00
4  17       0  00:00:00
5  18   60000  06:00:00
```